# Echoing a JSTree List Item that is checked by default with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jstree

The question is very simple, im trying to echo with PHP a JSTree List Item that is checked by default.

According to all the information that i've found on similar issues, I should be able to echo an active list item by just adding `class="jstree-checked"` but its not working for me.

This is the code that I'm currently using. **This code shows up a list item that is not checked**.

```
echo '<li class="jstree-checked" id="id">List Item that should be checked on load but its not</li>';
```

This is my JS Tree code

```
    <script>    
    var select_data = '';

    $(function () {
        $("#tree").jstree({
            "checkbox": {
                'keep_selected_style': false,
'three_state': false,
'cascade': '',
            },
                "plugins": ["checkbox"],    
        });
        $("#tree").bind("changed.jstree",
            function (e, data) {
                console.log(data);

                select_data = JSON.stringify(data.selected);

            }
        );
    }); 


    $.jstree._reference('#tree').check_node('#test'); 

    function upload() {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        var url = "../../jstree/ajax.php?select_data=" + select_data;

        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send(); 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I guess it's not a php related question. Because echo code works but list item is not checked. So php works, but jstree doesnt. The problem is in front-end, jstree

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to show a single node with a mix of checked/non-checked list items, but since  I still didn't manage to fix this, i found out a temporary solution.

I'm echoing two different nodes, one for the list items that should be checked, and another one for the list items that should not be checked.

After that, I just added this to the script:

```
$(function(){
$('#tree').jstree(true).select_node('active_items_node');
});
```

With this little function, my #active_items_node will load up on default checked state.